# Transformation not updating the element

Tags: raphael

```
var m = ele.matrix;
```

`m.translate(10,10)` // this line updates the 'e' and 'f' of the matrix. That too i can see the updated value only if i refresh the values in firebug

The element is not getting translated. Please let me know how to make the element obey the transformation when i change the matrix of the element.

full code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #canvas_container {  
                width: 500px;  
                border: 1px solid #aaa;  
            }  
    </style>
</head>
<body><div id="canvas_container"></div></body>
<script>
window.onload = function() {    
    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);     
    text = paper.text(150,150,"Some Text");     
    text.transform("m1,0,0,1,5,0")  
} 
</script>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: Some *MORE* sample code?

Answer (score 1):

I think the transformation is working, but it is executing immediately, so you don't get to see it move. Try transforming after a timeout to see it:

```
setTimeout(function() {text.transform("m1,0,0,1,5,0")}, 2000);
```

**Edit**: Ok, I looked at this a little more and discovered some things that might help. You can follow along in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cordesmj/GnLf3/).

Using the matrix property of an element is not really documented (and I am wondering why Matrix is documented at all, because it seems like it is used internally, but not really intended for use by users of Raphael), and the only way I could figure out to apply it to the element was by getting the transform string for the matrix and applying it using `element.transform()`. One of the problems is that `Matrix.toTransformString()` seems to have a bug in that, if either x or y translation is 0, translation gets lost completely (I just reported this to Dmitry). I was able to get it to return a matrix string by passing in `{isSimple: false}` and it sort of works.

However, it is worth noting that using this method, all rotation and scaling seems to be relative to the origin, which is somewhat cumbersome (unless you are more well versed in matrix transformations than I am, which wouldn't be hard). Anyway, the fiddle runs a bunch of combinations of transformations on several elements. It is kind of sloppy, but I think it may give you some ideas on how to proceed with the matrix transformations (or if you are better off just using the element transformation functions [like translate, scale and rotate] directly).

Comment: transform method is working. But when i manipulate the matrix like ele.matrix.translate(dx,dy) , the translation is not applied to the element. Do i need to call some other method like ele.update()